# Rails - Nested Model Fails to Save

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I'm rather new to Rails and I'm writing a signup form that includes nested models. When I submit the form, the user is saved just fine, but the nested model does not save anything to the Subscription db, and the console throws no errors.

I sincerely hope I'm not missing something insanely obvious, and I appreciate any tips you can share. Thanks!

Here is the code-

Models:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :posts, :name, :price
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plan
  has_many :events
  has_one :subscription, :autosave => true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscription

  attr_accessible :subscription_attributes

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      email:email, 
      plan: plan_id,
      card: stripe_card_token )
    self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
    save!
  end
  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
    false
  end
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :plan_id, :status, :user_id
  belongs_to :user

end
```

This is the User controller:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
  @user = plan.user
  @user.build_subscription
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save_with_payment
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the SendEvent!"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

This is the form:

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => {:class => "form-inline"} do |f|  %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :name, :class => "control-label" %> 
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>  

    # A few more fields here and...

    # The nested model:
    <%= f.fields_for :subscription do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.hidden_field :status, :value => true %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary", id: "submitacct" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you tried creating the User in the Rails console?

Comment: The 'new' and 'create' methods within the Subscription class are intentional?

Comment: They aren't intentional, I added then when I was in "so desperate to fox this I'll try anything" mode. I edited the post to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Sample app from [RailsCasts](http://www.railscasts.com)

[RailsCasts Episode #196: Nested Model Form (revised)](https://github.com/railscasts/episode-196/tree/master/revised/questionnaire-after)

Maybe help you.

Comment: @Soliah I can create the user in the Rails console but I don't know how to include nested attributes in the User.new console command.

I tried using
    usernew = User.new( :name => "Name", :email => "Email@email.com" , :subscription_attributes => { :status => "active" })

But it gives me a TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer